# Access 2013 Default Value Expression Builder Issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to do a default value in a text box that is a default value for a form which has a specific file path added to a file name. However when I put the following into the expression builder for the default value I get a #Name? error in the form text box.

```
=DLookUp("[FilePath]","[DEFAULT_FILE_PATHS]","[DEFAULT_FILE_PATHS].ID = 4") & Year([Date]) & Format(DateAdd("m",-1,[Date]),"mm") & " Sales Summary.csv"
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Year([Date]) & Format(DateAdd("m",-1,[Date]),"mm")` Remove the brackets around [Date] in case you want to use date function else it would be considered as field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=DLookUp("[FilePath]","[DEFAULT_FILE_PATHS]","[DEFAULT_FILE_PATHS].ID = 4") & Format(DateAdd("m",-1, Date()),"yyyymm") & " Sales Summary.csv"
```